# How is PCManFM being launched at session start?

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, pcmanfm

PCManFM  is being launched at every session start, taking control over the desktop.

Neither `~/.xprofile`, `~/.config/`, `/etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart`, nor `~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart` have a line for PCManFM.

Where could this be happening?

Also, I've tried to work around this by running `pcmanfm --desktop-off` after a 1 seconds sleep in `~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart`, but sometimes pcmanfm still takes control over the desktop.

Comment: Have you looked at `~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/desktop.conf`. There's a line with `desktop_manager/command=filemanager`. I don't use Lubuntu now but what do you see when you right-click in an empty space on your desktop. Is there an option to turn off PCManFM from controlling the desktop?

Comment: Removing `filemanager` from that line did the trick, thanks!. Could you make your comment into an answer?

Comment: I have no problem if you convert the comment to an answer yourself detailing exactly what you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @DK_Bose suggestion, I edited the file `~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/desktop.conf`, removing the word `filemanager` from the line `desktop_manager/command=filemanager`. This stopped PCManFM from launching at session start.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a GUI way to do this In the main LXDE menu hover the mouse over preferences and click on default applications for lxsession. Then you can select the tab that says core applications and then there is a text box for Desktop manager and you can hold backspace for it to not have pcmanfm manage the desktop. Although this GUI application edits saves the data in ~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/desktop.conf. Then it will not take over the wallpaper the next time you log in.